# Paperclip + S3 Amazon region error

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, region

I read a lot of stuff about this, but still i can't fix my error.
Error i got is: 
`Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError (missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']):`

My production.rb :
`config.paperclip_defaults = {
       :storage => :s3,
       :region => 'eu-central-1',
       :s3_credentials => {
       :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
       :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
       :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I just add: 
  `:s3_region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],`
 to `production.rb`
then run 
 `heroku config:set AWS_REGION=my_region`

Now it upload images properly